# Configure AD VM on Hyper-V to provide AD services on user network (on one NIC) and logging on management network (separate NIC)

Tags: active-directory, hyper-v

As the topic suggests, I want to have the AD VM on Hyper-V connect to two different VLANs (100 and 200) which are different physical networks. One physical network (VLAN 100) is where all the user desktops lie (Need AD for user authentication) and one physical network is (VLAN 200) where I will forward the Event logs (Application, Security Events on the AD VM to.

These are two separate VLAN networks which require different physical NICs, in order to address a requirement to have logging on a separate segment.

How should I connect the AD VM to one Virtual Switch for user desktop segment and to another Virtual Switch for logging segment? Any pointers will be most appreciated!

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation from Microsoft (and others) that Multi-homed domain controllers are not recommended?  Here is a documented workaround (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/9743befb-e48c-8175-8a16-8e96b68c42a9), though in my experience these workarounds are not 100% reliable and may (depending upon how the second VLAN is configured) eventually lead to authentication and replication failures.

If traffic on VLAN200 is restricted, clients and other DCs may get an SRV for VLAN200 and attempt to contact the DC on that address, and fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I connect the AD VM to one Virtual Switch for user desktop
> segment and to another Virtual Switch for logging segment?

Connect each virtual NIC to each respective virtual switch and assign each virtual NIC a valid ip address in each respective network.